# Local Firebase remote config plist can't be read when launching without app internet

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, swiftui, firebase-remote-config

I have problems with firebase remote config reading from local .plist file (default values provided in case if user has no internet connection when fetching remote config values on first app open).

This happens ONLY when launching app in offline mode.
Just to update:

1. file name is 100% correct. Checked many times.
2. checked plist file - maybe corrupted or something with terminal command: plutil PATH - all good.

Currently setup:

When initialising remote config service:

```
let settings = RemoteConfigSettings()
settings.minimumFetchInterval = 0
RemoteConfig.remoteConfig().setDefaults(fromPlist: remoteConfigDefaults)
RemoteConfig.remoteConfig().configSettings = settings
```

Then trying to read array value:

```
func arrayValue(forKey key: RemoteConfigKey) -> [String] {
    if localStorage.isRemoteConfigDebugEnabled,
        let localValue = localStorage.getRemoteConfigValue(forKey: key) as? String {
        return localValue.components(separatedBy: ",")
    }
    return value(forKey: key).jsonValue as? [String] ?? []
}
```

and value is:

```
func value(forKey key: RemoteConfigKey) -> RemoteConfigValue {
    RemoteConfig.remoteConfig().configValue(forKey: key.rawValue)
}
```

The problem actually is only with arrays and strings. Int and booleans works just fine (exactly same method, just instead of jsonValue as [String] used .boolValue or .numberValue.IntValue and .doubleValue.

Was trying to debug for a while. Updated to latest firebase SDK, nothing helped.

Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I have digged deeper and found a reason. So in case someone needs the answer and has the same issue:

There were a complex of things that had to be fixed:

1. Firebase SDK had an issue, that was fixed in 8.0 version, so had to update Firebase sdk
2. There were wrong quetes used in plist file, so just check that questes are normal.
3. FirebaseApp.configure() (in my case it was with settings, but nevertheless it is the same) has to be called before setting remote config settings